# SQLAlchemy: Trigger not firing on INSERT

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with a trigger that doesn't fire through a `.merge()` call in SQLAlchemy. 
I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_comment_count
BEFORE INSERT ON mediacomment
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_comment_count();
```

The trigger executes the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_comment_count() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE channel_users
        SET comment_count = comment_count + 1,
        last_comment = NEW.created_time
        WHERE
        channel_id = (SELECT ch.channel_id FROM media m
                      INNER JOIN channel ch ON ch.user_id = m.user_id
                      WHERE m.media_id = NEW.media_id)
        AND user_id = NEW.user_id;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger works great if I do a SQL-based INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO medialike VALUES (999292999,'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000',367668179,true,'770160534981089486_12336189');
```

**However**, when I use the SQLAlchemy's `.merge()` method, a row is inserted but the trigger is not fired:

```
com = MediaComment(
      is_follower=is_follower,
      comment_text=comment['txt'],
      comment_id_native=str(comment['id']),
      created_time=comment['time'],
      user_id=str(comment['id']),
      media_id=self.media_id
      )
self.session.merge(com)
self.session.commit()
```

Any ideas of what could cause this problem? 
I'm running PostgreSQL-9.4 and Python3

Comment: Are you sure it's actually emitting an `INSERT` and not an `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by enabling logging and examining the log files in `pg_log`. The reason was that the transaction with the `INSERT`, that should have fired the trigger, was being rolled back.